# Where can i find IBM WAS library API

Tags: java, sdk, websphere

I want to know API for the following IBM WAS package. Could any one suggest/guide me to website where i can find the API for WAS class/packages/interface.

```
Class   : com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection
package : com.ibm.ws.rsadapter
Version : 8.5.5.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please search for the following jar file on your machine and confirm if you are able to locate these classes or not in it.
com.ibm.ws.runtime

Refer following link

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/overview-summary.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-17-0-4

WSJdbcConnection class has been deprecated since WAS 7.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21215817

You may also look for com.ibm.ws.jdbc_1.0.8.jar and generate javadoc

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, your r right. I have already found this in the Appserver library. But, I need an IBM api list where i can check which class and methods fit for my requirement.

Comment: Please can you check your <wasroot>/AppServer/web/index.html if it has javadocs. ELse you can look at generating the javadocs using the link :: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#runningjavadoc

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You can find API javadocs for WAS at the above link

Comment: Hi Naresh, Please advise if your problem is resolved. Can we mark this question as closed.